# How to format nested collection in Blue Prism

Tags: collections

I am retrieving some information with Blue Prism from one API, and I receive a collection as the output. The problem is that I do not want my collection to look like this. I want to receive one collection with one row where I will have all of the employees listed, not 1 employee per 1 collection. Now I'm getting a collection with many nested collections, and each of them has 1 row. I tried to use a loop with utility collection manipulation - Copy rows and also Collections - Copy Rows, but it did not work. Could anyone tell me, how can I format my collection to get only 1 collection with all of the information in it, please?
Best regards[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are on V6 you can use dot notation to get the values directly out of nested collections (confirmed working on v6.4 on my machine) where you can reference the active rows data like this

```
0_Results.JSON:Array.id
```

this would pull out the id value from the nested collection in the active row. If accessing the data is not what you're after and you'd like to transpose the data into one collection you can follow these steps.

Create a holding and a resulting collection. In your collections define what columns you want. Add a row to the resulting collection then parse or transpose the nested collection into the holding collection that singular row of data out into the resulting collection.

You can then loop this for as many rows present in the collection.

Secondarily if nested loop referencing works for you you could also just use calculation stages to transpose each nested collection into a resulting collection, adding a row as you go each time to the resulting collection.

Example of what I mean:
[image]

code copied here, just copy and paste it into Blue Prism to see it (its v6 code it might muck about with X/Y co-ordinates FYI if it does its just because they can't be read properly its not broken, just click and drag them about to reset their values)

```
<process name="__selection___sandbox"><stage stageid="c77f14c8-f5d9-407f-a640-c8288b067311" name="Start" type="Start"><display x="15" y="-105" /><onsuccess>68da3612-99fd-48aa-8e5f-87e98b60d313</onsuccess></stage><stage stageid="0b03892d-6e8c-459f-a460-ef3c2deacd8b" name="End" type="End"><display x="15" y="345" /></stage><stage stageid="9061b1aa-becf-4335-afc5-bc52e4398833" name="Stage1" type="ProcessInfo"><display x="-195" y="-105" w="150" h="90" /></stage><stage stageid="36ecf838-de7d-4a2c-b376-ef865d3036c3" name="Coll1" type="Collection"><display x="-195" y="-15" /><datatype>collection</datatype><private /><alwaysinit /><collectioninfo><field name="Field2" type="collection" /></collectioninfo><initialvalue><row><field name="Field2" type="collection"><row /><row /><row /></field></row></initialvalue></stage><stage stageid="fa5aa372-f90d-4e71-bdf0-17b58613d666" name="Coll2" type="Collection"><display x="-195" y="30" /><datatype>collection</datatype><private /><alwaysinit /><collectioninfo><field name="Field1" type="text" /><field name="Field2" type="text" /></collectioninfo><initialvalue><row><field name="Field1" type="text" value="some" /><field name="Field2" type="text" value="value" /></row></initialvalue></stage><stage stageid="68da3612-99fd-48aa-8e5f-87e98b60d313" name="store collection into each other" type="Calculation"><loginhibit onsuccess="true" /><display x="15" y="-45" /><onsuccess>8aa44d85-7b12-422d-8e73-086caa454b24</onsuccess><calculation expression="[Coll2]" stage="Coll1.Field2" /></stage><stage stageid="289b8719-8c2a-4dcd-9065-e2a372f69c97" name="Holding Collection" type="Collection"><display x="-195" y="90" /><datatype>collection</datatype><private /><alwaysinit /></stage><stage stageid="b84dacab-9113-44b8-9562-af9244d3a0e0" name="Result Collection" type="Collection"><narrative>Data types are known so make it a defined collection</narrative><display x="-195" y="135" /><datatype>collection</datatype><private /><alwaysinit /><collectioninfo><field name="Field1" type="text" /><field name="Field2" type="text" /></collectioninfo></stage><stage stageid="8aa44d85-7b12-422d-8e73-086caa454b24" name="Loop Start1" type="LoopStart"><loginhibit onsuccess="true" /><display x="15" y="45" /><onsuccess>3c60f50f-8239-4b72-b8f0-a85fa61892fb</onsuccess><groupid>abb7f83d-3fe5-4a94-b482-329c0bef2b2e</groupid><looptype>ForEach</looptype><loopdata>Coll1</loopdata></stage><stage stageid="9e85a5ba-7bec-4ffc-afd7-f893dae57e36" name="Loop End1" type="LoopEnd"><loginhibit onsuccess="true" /><display x="15" y="285" /><onsuccess>0b03892d-6e8c-459f-a460-ef3c2deacd8b</onsuccess><groupid>abb7f83d-3fe5-4a94-b482-329c0bef2b2e</groupid></stage><stage stageid="b9ebc4f4-ce70-4774-ab61-b66e7ab86daa" name="store nested collection into holding collection" type="Calculation"><loginhibit onsuccess="true" /><display x="15" y="165" /><onsuccess>5359c508-e598-485f-82e6-3123354ed4b2</onsuccess><calculation expression="[Coll1.Field2]" stage="Holding Collection" /></stage><stage stageid="5359c508-e598-485f-82e6-3123354ed4b2" name="Parse into result collection" type="MultipleCalculation"><loginhibit onsuccess="true" /><display x="15" y="225" /><onsuccess>9e85a5ba-7bec-4ffc-afd7-f893dae57e36</onsuccess><steps><calculation expression="[Holding Collection.Field1]" stage="Result Collection.Field1" /><calculation expression="[Holding Collection.Field2]" stage="Result Collection.Field2" /></steps></stage><stage stageid="3c60f50f-8239-4b72-b8f0-a85fa61892fb" name="give collection a row" type="Action"><loginhibit onsuccess="true" /><display x="15" y="105" /><inputs><input type="text" name="Collection Name" friendlyname="Collection Name" narrative="The name of the collection to act upon" expr="&quot;Result Collection&quot;" /></inputs><onsuccess>b9ebc4f4-ce70-4774-ab61-b66e7ab86daa</onsuccess><resource object="Blueprism.AutomateProcessCore.clsCollectionActions" action="Add Row" /></stage><stage stageid="ba8aff04-6920-4fc6-bd03-70041755eaba" name="this is set up ignore this" type="Block"><loginhibit onsuccess="true" /><display x="-30" y="-75" w="105" h="60" /><font family="Segoe UI" size="10" style="Regular" color="7FB2E5" /></stage><stage stageid="20e37f34-29e5-495f-9a02-3f87ff0c147f" name="answer in description" type="Block"><loginhibit onsuccess="true" /><narrative>loop over collection with values, push those values into holding collection where you can use a multi calc to target specific columns of data to transpose into the results collection then the loop stage allows you to get as many rows out as you like</narrative><display x="-30" y="15" w="105" h="300" /><font family="Segoe UI" size="10" style="Regular" color="7FB2E5" /></stage></process>
```

Dex